# Facebook debugger fail?

Tags: facebook, thumbnails

This is my page:
http://www.youtubelearn.com/the-copenhagen-wheel

I've already given the correct meta data. But facebook scraper couldn't get it.
Several weeks ago, the debugger showed "400 bad request".
But for now, the debugger shows this:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtubelearn.com%2Fthe-copenhagen-wheel

How can I solve this problem?